# Is $\mathbb{P}(S_n/n>p+a)$ a decreasing function of n?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions

In my question, I have i.i.d random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ $\sim \text{Bern}(p)$ (Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$). 
Denote $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$. Does $\mathbb{P}(S_n/n>p+a)$ decrease when $n$ increases, where $a$ is a fixed positive value?

**Update**: or when $n$ is big enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not decrease, but oscillates. 
Here is a graph of the probability in question for $p=1/2, a=1/10$, for $n=1$ up to $n=100$. A rigorous proof can be achieved by analysing the probability in question, given by

$$P\{\frac{S_n}{n}>p+a\}=\sum_{k>n(p+a)}{n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
which follows from the fact that $S_n/n$ takes the value $k/n$ with probability ${n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add very simple observation which works for every sequence with bounded variance.
 Let $p_n = \mathbb{P}\left({S_n \over n} > p + \alpha\right)$. Let's calculate $\mathbb{D} {S_n \over n} = {1 \over n^2} \mathbf{Var} (S_n) = {1 \over n} \mathbf{Var} (X_1)$. Thus, by the Chebyshov's inequality $p_n \le {\mathbb{D} {S_n \over n} \over \alpha^2} = \mathbf{Var}(X_1) {1 \over n \alpha^2}$. Thus $p_n$ is bounded by a decreasing sequence, hence it contains a decreasing subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

This probability does decrease as $n$ grows.

A heuristic justification is that as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $S_n/n \rightarrow p$, in probability. That is for any $\epsilon > 0$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbf{P}(|S_n/n - p| > \epsilon) = 0.$$

I'm sure its possible to prove this for small $n$ using direct calculation using inequalities for binomial coefficients (I'll leave that to someone else).

Since the sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli $p$ variables has a binomial $\text{Bin}(n,p)$ distribution, an argument for the limiting case is that the [De Moivre - Laplace Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem) asserts as $n \rightarrow \infty$

$$ \text{Bin}(n,p) \sim N\big(np,np(1-p) \big)$$

Therefore (using properties of expectations and variance)

$$\left( \frac{1}{n}S_n -p \right) \sim N \left( 0, \frac{p(1-p)}{n}\right).$$

So that in the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ your question is

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbf{P}\left(  N \left( 0, \frac{p(1-p)}{n}\right) > a \right) = 0.$$

One can of course show that the probability for the normal distribution above is decreasing in $n$, though you need to be careful with the fact that the Binomial approximation to the Normal holds only in the limit.

Comment: Wrong. The probability does not decrease in general. For example, take $a=1/7$ and $p=1/2$. Then $S_2/2$ has the distribution $1$ and $0$ with probability $1/4$ each, and$1/2$ with probability $1/2$, so $P(S_2/2>1/2+1/7)=1/4$, but $S_3/3$ has the distribution $1$ and $0$ with probability $1/8$, $2/3$ and $1/3$ with probability $3/8$ each, so $P(S_3/3 > 1/2+1/7)=1/2$.

Comment: I think you're over simplyifying to start your response with  "Wrong". I agree 100% with your answer that this oscillates. As I observed in my post above, I did not address the case of finite $n$. My answer was entirely addressing the limiting case, and is clearly caveated as such. Without knowing the poster's reason for asking, it is impossible to tell whether the motivation is to literally know if this is a decreasing function (as you've shown computationally, no), or to have a justification as to why this would tend to 0 (which I've justified theoretically to be yes).

Comment: Thank both of you very much. I know $S_n/n$ will converge to $p$. My original concern is whether it will strictly decrease or converge with oscillation. I think about this question when I was dealing with my former question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609205/bound-the-probability-that-one-random-variable-deviates-from-its-expected-value. I'm wondering if you can take a look at this question and give some advice. Thank you so much.

Comment: @owen88 - Thank you for your reply. Mathematics is known for its precision. The statement "the sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ is decreasing function of $n$" means precisley this: If $n_1>n_2$, then $a_{n_1}<a_{n_2}$. It does NOT mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. As a result, when you write "The probability does decrease as $n$ grows", you are wrong. In other words, your statement is logically false.